# Find the sum of a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find the sum of a given power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+4)x^{n-3}$$

I'm trying to find the sum through slow integration or differentiation of a series. But, unfortunately, I can't find the right combination for this, although it's probably a simple one. I know there are a bunch of other ways to find the sum of a power series, but I'm interested in solving this example through slow integration/differentiation.

Comment: $n-3=(n+4) -7$.

Comment: the first term is $4x^{-3}$. is this right? Not quite a power series then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+4)x^{n-3}$$
$$=x^{-3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+4)x^n$$
$$=x^{-3}\big[x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\big]$$
$$=x^{-2}\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{1}{1-x}\big)+\frac{4}{x^{3}(1-x)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{x^2(1-x)^2}+\frac{4(1-x)}{x^{3}(1-x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{x^3(x-1)^2}\big[x+4(1-x)\big]=\frac{4-3x}{x^3(1-x)^2}$$
when $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+4)x^{n-3}&=x^{-6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+4)x^{n+3}\\
&=x^{-6}\frac d{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+4}\right)\\
&=x^{-6}\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{x^4}{1-x}\right).\\
\end{align}